# Java app throws ClosedByInterruptException immediately when opening a socket, cause?

Tags: java, sockets, exception, interrupted-exception

I have a java app that holds open many connections to an address, probably in the ballpark of 2,000 at once, with hardly any activity, mostly open for monitoring purposes passing a few bytes every now and then. When new connections need to be opened up, it automatically opens them and adds them to its pool. Sometimes though, for an unknown reason, the application receives a ClosedByInterruptException immediately during/after creating the socket to the remote address. To the best of my knowledge, this only occurs on the client side as a result of an interrupt signal to the thread. I have checked and rechecked the source code surrounding the problem area and it seems ok. I was hoping I could get someone's expertise as to if there could be an alternate cause, besides source code, for instance, is there a system reason that causes this? Is there a hardware cause? Server level/router level? My network knowledge I would consider amateur, but is 2K connections too many for a router, or no?

```
INFO  [08 Sep 2011 23:11:45,982]: Reconnecting id 20831
ERROR [08 Sep 2011 23:11:45,990]: IOException while creating plain socket channel
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:184)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:518)
    at com.*.createSocketChannelPlain(MyTask.java:441)
    at com.*._executeTask(MyTask.java:176)
    at com.*.executeTask(MyTask.java:90)
    at com.*.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:55)
ERROR [08 Sep 2011 23:11:45,990]: Could not open socket
WARN  [08 Sep 2011 23:11:45,990]: WorkerThread_24 received interrupted exception in ThreadPool
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at com.*.TaskQueue.getTask(TaskQueue.java:39)
    at com.*.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:48)
```

**Update:** I would like to try and offer all I can to help others contribute to a diagnosis. So here is the actual function where the exception occurs, only difference being the line marking I added to line 441.

```
private SocketChannel createSocketChannelPlain() throws TaskFailedException {
    SocketChannel socketChannel = null;
    try {
        // Create a non-blocking socket channel to use to communicate for imap connection
        socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        try {socketChannel.socket().setSoLinger(true, 0);} catch (Exception e) {}
        try {socketChannel.socket().setKeepAlive(true);} catch (Exception e) {}
        /*Line 441*/ socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(_HOSTNAME, _PORT));
        //System.out.println("Started connection");

        // Complete connection
        while (!socketChannel.finishConnect()) {
            // do something until connect completed
            try {
                //do what you want to do before sleeping
                Thread.sleep(500);//sleep for 500 ms
                //do what you want to do after sleeping
            } catch(InterruptedException ie){
                //If this thread was interrupted by another thread 
                try { socketChannel.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
                finally { socketChannel = null; }
                break;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("Finished connecting");

        return socketChannel;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("IOException while creating plain socket channel to gmail", e);
        try { socketChannel.close(); } catch (Exception e1) {}
        finally { socketChannel = null; }
        //throw new TaskFailedException("IOException occurred in createSocketChannel");
    }
    return socketChannel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running this on?  I don't know about Windows, but on Linux (and presumably other Unix-like OSes), you can run out of file handles by having large numbers of sockets.  You can work around this by doing `ulimit -n 8192` or similar before running the Java app.  Alternatively, edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` and set `nofile`.  All of that said, `ClosedByInterruptedException` would be an odd way to notice this.

If the above isn't the issue, the next thing I'd try would be to run `tcpdump` (if we're talking about a GUI-less machine) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (if we aren't) and capture the traffic your program's generating, looking for weird things happening at the time that connection starts.

Comment: It's linux, Debian. I actually ran into the file descriptor issue before and the exception description I constantly received then was "Bad hostname". Since then I've set the startup script to raise the limit considerably. `tcpdump`ing though is actually a great idea that I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Turns out sysadmin didn't let me tcpdump it...Will have to try this out on a personal system later.

Comment: Or, if you give him the command, he might do it for you?  `tcpdump -i any -s 0 -w /tmp/casey.pcap port 80` would be about right, I'm guessing?  Maybe add Google's network and your source IP as restrictions, to avoid dumping anyone else's traffic...

Comment: @casey, did you get anywhere with this?  I'd be interested in the result, if you get one.  I've never had this particular effect, but we operate some systems that do similar things...

Comment: On Mac OS use launchctl - http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Mac-OS-X